# Setting up letsencript with Icecast, how do I document this in my docker-compose.override.yml file?

Tags: ssl

I am trying to set up a self-signed SSL certificate, generated by certbot.  I converted the certificate into a usable format, but every time I try to document this in a docker-compose.override.yml file, I get errors.  How do I do this correctly, as I'm not understanding the documentation's wording of this.  Here's the example from the documatation from the Application I'm trying to work with.  I've converted the certificate and the privkey files.

- `/path/on/host/to/ssl.crt:/var/azuracast/acme/ssl.crt:ro`
- `/path/on/host/to/ssl.key:/var/azuracast/acme/ssl.key:ro`

I guess I'm trying to figure out what the rest of this means.  my path to these files is: `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com`
Here's what's what the file is supposed to look like once finished:
services:
web:
volumes

- /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/example.cert:/var/azuracast/acme/ssl.crt:ro
- /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/example.com.key:/var/azuracast/acme/ssl.key:ro  This broke up the lines, but this is what my docker-compose.override.yml file is supposed to look.  Can someone please tell me what my error is here?

Comment: Are you asking how Docker folder mappings work?

Comment: I think what I want to find out, is how do I compose the document so that I can restart the container without errors.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: It will say something like: "services is a mapping, not an nontype.  I believe that's what it says.  They say you should edit it this way: - /path/on/host/to/ssl.key:/var/azuracast/acme/ssl.key:ro

Comment: Include your entire docker compose file.

Comment: - /etc/pki/tls/private/crosshosting.tk.key:/etc/letsencrypt/ssl.key:ro  This is from github, this where I got this example.  The icecast server, expects an RSA key file, so I used SSL to convert the certificate from certbot.

Comment: services: web: volumes: - /path/on/host/to/ssl.crt:/var/azuracast/acme/ssl.crt:ro
    All os this is supposed to be on multiple lines, but this is what the file's supposed to look like.  my certificate and key files are located at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/example.com.cert and /etc/letsencrypt/example.com/example.com.key, respectively.  - /path/on/host/to/ssl.key:/var/azuracast/acme/ssl.key:ro

Comment: [Edit] your question to add it.

Comment: Yes.  That's my question.  How do I add that?

Comment: You have to [Edit] your question to add the information you have added in the comments.